# Why isn't the Neo4j None function working in my query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm having trouble returning nodes which do not have a relationship with a certain property.

Here's the query to build the graph for the scenario:

```
create ({Name:'Foo1'})-[:T]->({Name:'Bar'})<-[:T{Inactive:true}]-({Name:'Foo2'})<-[:T]-({Name:'Foo3'})
```

Now to specify the desired result more:
I want to get all the nodes that are somehow connected to 'Bar'. So from the graph created with the query above I'd expect to get Foo1 and Foo3.

I'm having trouble getting nodes that do **NOT** have a relationship with the "Inactive" property using the following query:

```
match (bar)<-[rs*]-(foo) where ID(bar)= **BAR_ID**
optional match (foo)-[r]->() where r in rs
with foo, collect(distinct r) as relationships
where none(rel in relationships where rel.Inactive = true)
return foo
```

Now you might notice the query is a bit extravaganza with the second where clause. It's part of a different solution to a different problem, so please do not focus on that part unless it's part of my problem. The thing I am interested in is why the query fails to return anything at all. It seems the predicate of the *none()* function isn't working properly. Especially since replacing *none()* with *any()* will return only Foo2 as expected like so:

```
match (bar)<-[rs*]-(foo) where ID(bar)= **BAR_ID**
optional match (foo)-[r]->() where r in rs
with  foo, collect(distinct r) as relationships
where any(rel in relationships where rel.Inactive = true)
return foo
```

So, again, the question is why the query that uses the *none()* function isn't returning anything. First I thought it has might have something to do with some relationships not having the "Inactive" property but the [docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/working-with-null/), they tell you that missing properties evaluate as false (as it's null). At least, that's my interpretation which can be wrong of course.

I'm not interested in a solution to the problem since I've already written another query that does return Foo1 and Foo3. **I'm interested in finding out why the query in question isn't working.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the specificity of the work with the `Null`:

```
WITH [ null, false ] as values
RETURN none(value in values where value = true)

// return Null

with true as val where not (null = true)
return val

// returns nothing
```

[ http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/working-with-null/ ]

So, you need check `null`:

```
match (bar)<-[rs*]-(foo) where ID(bar)= **BAR_ID**
optional match (foo)-[r]->() where r in rs
with foo, collect(distinct r) as relationships
with foo, none(rel in relationships where rel.Inactive = true) as logic
          where logic is null or logic = true
return foo
```

Or, you can check if property `Inactive` exists or not:

```
match (bar)<-[rs*]-(foo) where ID(bar)= **BAR_ID**
optional match (foo)-[r]->() where r in rs
with foo, collect(distinct r) as relationships
where none(rel in relationships where exists(rel.Inactive) and rel.Inactive = true)
return foo
```